# A naive estimate for the distribution of the prime numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

As we know, the beginning to estimate the prime-counting function $\pi(n)$ is the product $n(1-1/2)(1-1/3)\cdots(1-1/p)$, where $p$ is the largest prime number $\le n $. This product assumes that the conditions of non-divisibility are independent, but can we correct this naive estimate in any meaningful way?

Obviously, the number of integers $\le n $ not divisible by 2 is approximately $n(1-1/2)$. If we continue our sieve and assume that the non-divisibility is independent, the number of integers not divisible by 3 is approximately $n(1-1/3)$. But perhaps a term  $n(1-1/(2\cdot3))(1-1/3)$ is more accurate when we delete every sixth number in the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$.

That is, does the product $[n(1-1/(2\cdot3))](1-1/2)(1-1/3)$ lead to a better approximation for integers that are not divisible by 2 or by 3?

The next step would be $[n(1-1/(2\cdot3))(1-1/(2\cdot5))(1-1/(3\cdot5))](1-1/2)(1-1/3)(1-1/5)$ etc., but apparently this method does not lead to any meaningful analytic expression.

Comment: Would it not be $n(1+\frac{1}{6})(1-\frac{1}{2})(1-\frac{1}{3})$ ? Since you already double counting multiples of 6, i.e. removing them twice, so you would want to add them back in once

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your  $n(1-1/(2\cdot3))(1-1/3) = \frac59n$ or how you derive it. The natural pattern is being left with $\frac12n$ then $\frac13n$ then $\frac4{15}n$ and so on numbers in either of the following approaches.

First method: remove $\frac12$ of the numbers, then $\frac13$ of the remaining numbers, then $\frac15$ of the remaining numbers, ..., so being left with $n(1-\frac12)(1-\frac13)(1-\frac15)\cdots$ numbers.  So far you are left with $\frac4{15}n \cdots$ and this will get smaller with more steps.

Second method: remove $\frac12$ of the numbers, then $\frac13(1-\frac12)$ of the original numbers, then $\frac15(1-\frac12 - \frac13(1-\frac12))$  of the original numbers, ..., so being left with $n-\frac12n - \frac13(n-\frac12n) -\frac15(n-\frac12n - \frac13(1-\frac12)n)-\cdots$ numbers. So far you are again left with $\frac4{15}n- \cdots$ and this will also get smaller with more steps.

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion makes the approximation worse, not better, even for small $n$.

If $n$ is divisible by $6$, then any sequence of $n$ consecutive numbers has *exactly* $n \left(1-\frac 12\right) \left(1-\frac 13\right)$ elements which are not divisible by $2$ or $3$.

This is because we want to remove numbers of the forms $6k$, $6k+2$, $6k+3$, and $6k+4$, leaving just numbers of the forms $6k+1$ and $6k+5$.

When $n$ is large and not divisible by $6$, then $1$–$2$ of the extra $1$–$5$ numbers in the remainder of $n/6$ are not divisible by $2$ or $3$, and these differences are negligible when taking the ratio.

If your first step is to remove the approximately $\frac n6$ numbers divisible by $6$, then of the remaining approximately $\frac 56 n$ numbers, about $\frac 25 n$ are divisible by $2$ and about $\frac 15 n$ are divisible by $3$. So a more correct formula is $n \left(1-\frac 16\right) \left(1- \frac 35\right)$, and this is equal to $n \left(1-\frac 12\right) \left(1-\frac 13\right)$.